# real-time redis pub-sub makes variable invalid

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redis

I am subscribed to a redis real-time stream like so:

```
var currentVar;
redisClient.on('message', function(channel, message) {
     currentVar = message;
}
```

So as a message is recieved, a global variable currentVar is set to it.  As long as atleast one message is coming through the stream, currentVar SHOULD NEVER BE UNDEFINED(all messages are defined for sure).  However, when it is called like so:

```
app.get('/currentVar', function(req, res) {
console.log(currentVar);
}
```

The variable currentVar will have an undefined value quite often.  I believe this is because the redis pub-sub is streaming too fast for JS to keep up, but I do not know.

How can I assign currentVar so that it is never undefined?

Comment: Are these two pieces of code in the same file?

Comment: yes they are @BarışUşaklı

Comment: Post your publishing code as well.